# Execute sequence of methods in Scala one by one and continue only if the previous one return true

Tags: scala

I am using scala to wrap around STAF to run a test that has multiple steps.

Basically each step is a method call that returns a boolean. The steps are executed in a sequential order. I am wondering if there is a way to tell Scala to advance to the next step only if the previous one return true?

Thanks,

*EDIT*

Added an example below.

This is a list of steps for me to collect the data after the test. It has 3 steps. 1) zip the log, 2) copy the zipped archive somewhere and 3) clear the log directory

```
zipDir(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""", """C:\Logs.zip""")
copyFile(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs.zip""", "RepoMachine", """c:\data""")
clearDirContent(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""")
```

For me, it would only make sense to continue if previous steps has been executed correctly. For example, it wouldn't make sense to copy the zip file in step 2 if there is an error creating the zip file in the first place.

To illustrate my point, here is a verbose way to accomplish what I want:

```
var result = zipDir(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""", """C:\Logs.zip""")
if (result) 
    result = copyFile(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs.zip""", "RepoMachine", """c:\data""")
if (result) 
    result = clearDirContent(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""")
```

Comment: How about `listOfMethods.forall(f => f(x))`?

Comment: say if I have 2 methods a(p1:Int):Boolean and b(p2:Int):Boolean. If I place them in List(a(1), b(2)), would b be executed regardless of the result of a?

Comment: They probably would, you might consider using a Stream, I am not sure if it would fulfill your needs. Could you post some example code?

Comment: I have added an example of what I would like to accomplish. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your case you can use simple boolean and:

```
val result = zipDir(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""", """C:\Logs.zip""")
          && copyFile(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs.zip""", "RepoMachine", """c:\data""")
          && clearDirContent(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""")
```

`&&` unlike `&` stops on the first false value

**Outdated answer:**

How about `listOfMethods.forall(f => f(x))`? It short-circuits, so operations after first false wouldn't be executed:

```
scala> def a() = { println("A"); false } 
a: ()Boolean

scala> def b() = { println("B"); true }
b: ()Boolean                                          

scala> List(a _ ,b _ ).forall(f => f())
A
res2: Boolean = false
```

Important note: you have to place *closures* into your collection: if you write `List(a(1), b(2))` magic wont happen: a(1) and b(2) will be eagerly executed before they will be placed in the list. You can write something like:

```
def foo(x: Int) = { println ("Foo is " + x); false}
def bar(x: Int) = { println ("Bar is " + x); false}
List(
  () => foo(1), 
  () => bar(2)
).forall{ fun => fun() }
```

Comment: stupid me. I was overthinking the problem I have! It could have been easily solved by &&. Thanks

Comment: For your previous solution with "forall", is it possible to modify it to run functions that return arbitrary value (not just boolean)?

Comment: @defoo at the end of the day you'll need to have boolean, but you can pass `() => bar(2) == expectedValue` or something like this (or you're looking for something completely different?)

Comment: I guess it will solve my problem, although the syntax looks very similar to using for-comprehension. I just wanted to see if there is a less convoluted way of specifying the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any scala but using plain java you would just AND them together. As soon as a func returns false the expression is false and execution stops.

```
val result = fun1() && func2() && func3()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want for-comprehension with return of a scalaz's validation or some form of Either, so it would be

```
for {
  res1 <- func1
  res2 <- func2
  ...
} yield resN
```

this way, when your function returns a failure, it will stop where you failed.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic Scala way of doing this is with a [for-comprehension](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf#page=85). Your intermediate methods need to return a type that has .map and .flatMap defined on it--here, you can return an Option that is Some if the operation succeeded and None otherwise. If you want to preserve error messages, look into Validation or Either.

```
var result = for {
  zipped <- zipDir(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""", """C:\Logs.zip""")
  copied <- copyFile(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs.zip""", "RepoMachine", """c:\data""")
  cleared <- clearDirContent(handle, "testmachine1", """C:\Logs""")
} yield {
   cleared
}
```

`result` would be Some if all 3 operations took place and None otherwise. The operation short circuits if any of the intermediate steps don't return; under the hood, a for-comprehension uses [map and flat-map](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/).

The reason why I would suggest this over the short-circuiting AND is that it's much more flexible. For example, you might get to a point where you no longer want to hardcode filenames and paths, so you have zipDir return the full path to the zipped file if the zip operation succeeds. Your code could then look like

```
val result = for {
  zipped  <- zipDir(handle, machine, filepath)
  copied  <- copyFile(handle, machine, zipped, newlocation)
  cleared <- clearDirContent(handle, machine, filepath)
} yield cleared
```

Comment: Agree using for-comprehension would be more flexible as my method can now output something other than just boolean. But when I try out your solution, I hit an error "value flatMap is not a member of Boolean".

Comment: Yup, you'd need change the intermediate methods' return type. I was trying to avoid the dreaded m-word, but they need to return some kind of monad. Option would probably be easiest if you don't care about *why* they fail.